# graph.facebook get name & link and send to Database

Tags: javascript, json, facebook-graph-api

with the response_id from a post to the users wall I strip the user_id:

```
var userid = (response.post_id);
userid = userid.substring(0, userid.indexOf('_'));
```

Ok. Next I call the facebook graph:

```
$.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/' + userid + '?callback=?',function(data){
var name = data["name"];
var fblink = data["link"];
})
```

Now I try to save the data in a Database. So I do following:

```
$.post('<?php echo $siteurl; ?>write.php?fbusr_id=' + userid + '&fb_name=' + name + '&fb_link=' + fblink);
```

Problem: It works if I only send the fbusr_id but it doesnt work with fb_name & fb_link in the code. Nothing gets written to the database., If I cut fb_name & fb_link out of the $.post it works, the user_id gets written into the databse. 
That works:

```
$.post('<?php echo $siteurl; ?>write.php?fbusr_id=' + userid);
```

Cant find the reason. Thx for help.

Neil

Answer (score 0):

First reason, getJSON is asynchronous method you should use response data in their response function.

Second reason, POST method should send data as object instead of string parameter.

Thrid reason, if you really want to send data as query string parameter (maybe send by GET method) you should use encodeURIComponent(fblink) instead of fblink or something you want to send.
However, you may try this

```
$.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/' + userid + '?callback=?',function(data){
        var name = data["name"];
        var fblink = data["link"];
        $.post('<?php echo $siteurl; ?>write.php', {fbusr_id:userid,fb_name:name,fb_link:fblink},
                 function(response){} );
})
```